# Adding custom cidr to ingress security group using Lambda without default vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, vpc

First of all I have been searching stackflow and the internet for this but I didn't find exactly where the issue is.

Basically I am trying to add custom cidr ips to a security group via lambda function. I have given all the appropriate permissions (as far as i can tell) `[REMOVED]and also tried attaching the vpc (which is non-default) to the lambda function to access the security group[REMOVED]`.

But I am getting `"An error occurred (VPCIdNotSpecified) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: No default VPC for this user"`

**Policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "wafv2:GetIPSet",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "wafv2:UpdateIPSet"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxx:log-group:xxx:log-stream:*",
                "arn:aws:wafv2:us-west-2:xxx:*/ipset/*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Lambda function:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
    GroupId='sg-xxxxxxx'
    IpPermissions=[
        { 
            'FromPort': 443,
            'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
            'IpRanges': [
                {
                    'CidrIp': '1x.1x.x.1x/32',
                    'Description': 'adding test cidr using lambda'
                },
            ],
            'ToPort': 443
        }
        ],
        DryRun=True
    )
    return response
```

Could someone point me to the right direction? VPC is non-default. All I need is the add ingress rule to existing security group within non-default vpc

Thanks

Comment: Adding the Lambda function to the VPC will actually cause problems here, as it will prevent the Lambda function from accessing the AWS API (which exists outside the VPC). There is no need to configure the Lambda function to have VPC access "in order to access the security group" since you are not doing anything here that requires that type of network access, you are only connecting to the AWS API, and requesting that AWS modify a security group.

Comment: Also, `VpcId` is not a valid parameter for that method call https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.authorize_security_group_ingress

Comment: Thank you @MarkB. I have removed the VPC and also the VpcId but the issue still exist. Same error regarding No default VPC for this user. Is there anywhere I can specify which VPC to use?

Comment: The `GroupId` is enough for the system to know the VPC, since a security group can only belong to a single VPC. That's why VPC ID isn't a parameter of that function.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. The error remains however.

Comment: Yeah I really don't see any problem with your code. All I can suggest is trying some different options to debug the issue, maybe try it without `DryRun`. I upvoted your question to hopefully get more eyes on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: Initially it was syntax error but after googling i thought it requires vpc so I added VPC to the Lambda configuration which was not required for this purpose.
For anyone having the same issue (only want to update security group with the cidr): below is the correct function and permissions (function isnt complete as depending on the solution u may want to delete old rules too):

**Lambda function:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        DryRun=False,
        GroupId='sg-0123456789',
        IpPermissions=[
            { 
                'FromPort': 443,
                'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
                'IpRanges': [
                    {
                        'CidrIp': '1x.2x.3x.4x/32',
                        'Description': 'Security group updated via lambda'
                    }
                ],
                'ToPort': 443
            }
        ]
    )
    return response
```

**IAM Policy on lambda execution role:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:ModifySecurityGroupRules",
                "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn or all"
        }
    ]
}
```